# Extension cords flexible in cold weather

Tags: extension-cord

25+ year old 14/3 extension cord.  Blue jacket.  Still nice and flexible.  Jacket stamped "-50C".  Surprisingly, it is also stamped "SJTW-A".   I thought flexible-in-cold carried the E, not the T designation.  What is it that makes some extension cords flexible in cold weather?

Comment: I have found that "rubber" cords tend to be a lot more flexible in cold than the typical plastics, but they are also somewhat hard to find these days.

Answer (score 1):

You may notice a child's outdoor toy blanches and cracks in 6 months from UV from sunlight, but your car's interior holds up for 20 years despite much hotter conditions.  It is a different grade of plastic.

Also, nothing requires a cable claim every rating it's entitled to, or it may comply mostly, but fall technically short of what is needed for the rating.   You're always allowed to make a great product.

Answer (score 0):

Flexible cords have an entire section of the National Electric Code article 400. If I remember correctly T is thermoplastic, SJ is junior hard service, W is damp/ wet locations. I really don't remember A in a description.

Comment: Found this glossary:  http://uswireandcable.com/glossary.html

Comment: I know there are many more cord types in the NEC. Than that listing, type E cable is elevator according to the NEC different than your link, also w is wet/damp but I think type w is also sunlight resistant so that would be the same but I did not find a listing in the NEC for A

Comment: Per the document linked in Jerry's comment, "W-A" means weather approved.

Comment: I did look at the link but as I explained it differs from the NEC.